# Expected number of red balls in urn

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

We toss balls into urns. Denote with $x$ the number of balls in an urn. And $x_r$ denotes the number of red balls. The share of red balls among the balls is denoted as $P$. We toss these balls into urns in a manner such that $g(x) = 1/4 \,, x \in [0, 3]$, where $g(x)$ is the probability mass function of an urn of having $x$ balls.

Each urn will pick a winning ball. If there is a red ball among the balls, it will randomly pick a red ball. If there is none, if will pick at random among all its balls.

We want to determine that probability at which a red ball will get "picked" as a winning ball after it has been tossed into one of the urns.

One way of getting there is

$$ \frac{1}{E[X_r | x_r > 0 \wedge x > 0]}$$

Intuitively, if there is on average 3 red balls in urns where there is at least one red ball, then red balls have a 1/3 chance of becoming the winner.

For a numerical example, pick $P = 0.5$. Then

- $E[x_r | x_r > 0 \wedge x = 1] = 1$
- $E[x_r | x_r > 0 \wedge x = 2] = 1 + P = 3/2$
- $E[x_r | x_r > 0 \wedge x = 3] = 1 + 2P^2 + 2P(1-P)=2$

So the conditional expectation is $1/3 + 1/3 \cdot 3/2 + 1/3 \cdot 2 = 3/2$

Next, I tried to transform the expectation as

$$ E[X_r | x_r > 0] = \sum_{x_r=1}^3 Prob(x_r = X_R | x_r > 0 \wedge x > 0) x_r\\
= \frac{\sum_{x_r=1}^3 Prob(x_r = X_R \wedge x_r > 0 \wedge x > 0) x_r}{Prob(x_r > 0 \wedge x > 0)}\\
= \frac{\sum_{x_r=1}^3 Prob(x_r = X_R) x_r}{Prob(x_r > 0\wedge x > 0)}\\
= \frac{E[x_r]}{Prob(x_r > 0 \wedge x > 0)}$$

Again, in the numerical example above, $E[x_r] = 0.75$. The probability in the denominator however is $4/3(1/2 + 3/4 + 7/8) = 4/3 * 17/8 = 0.53125$

To get the conditional expectation of before, we need that

$$ \frac{3}{2} = \frac{E[x_r]}{Prob(x_r > 0 \wedge x > 0)} = \frac{\frac{3}{4}}{Prob(x_r > 0 \wedge x > 0)} $$

i.e., the probability must be 0.5. However, it is 0.51325, and hence the calculation appears to be off. Where did I slip? What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E[1/X]$ is not generally equal to $1/E[X]$.

$E[x_r\mid x_r>0\land x=2]=4/3$, not $3/2$, and $E[x_r\mid x_r>0\land x=3]=12/7$, not $2$,  if $P=1/2$. (It may be that the numbers you got are the ones you want but you expressed the expectation badly. What you wrote is the expected number of red balls given that *some* ball is red, but I think you wanted to identify a particular red ball in advance and calculate the expected number of red balls given that *that* ball is in the urn.)

When you combined the expectations $E[x_r\mid x_r>0\land x=1]$, 
$E[x_r\mid x_r>0\land x=2]$, and $E[x_r\mid x_r>0\land x=3]$, 
you gave them all equal weight ($1/3$).
But the three events $x_r>0\land x=1$, $x_r>0\land x=2$, and 
$x_r>0\land x=3$ are not equally likely and should have different weights.

Comment: It appears you are right, I miss-specified the expectation. If you'd care to help even more, here's a follow-up question on how to set up the expectation (conditional on the specific red ball) in general: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1651805/expected-number-of-red-balls-in-an-urn-a-specific-ball-being-in-it